# creating a type out of a static member

Tags: typescript

I am writing some typescript code using `ecsy`.

In there I have created a system(a class) like this

```
export class PointerSystem extends System {
    static queries = {
        interactable: {
            components: [Object3D, Interactable]
        },
        camera: {
            components: [Camera]
        },
    }
    queries: {
        interactable: {
            results: any[]
        }
    }
...
```

which works fine.
but the issue is that I would prefer not having to redefine all properties in `queries`.

And the root cause for this is that `ecsy` requires a static property with queries, but when the system executes it puts the values into the scope (`this`)

I've tried creating a record type with no real luck

```
queries: Record<keyof PointerSystem.queries, {results: any[]}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `keyof PointerSystem.queries`, try `keyof typeof PointerSystem.queries`. The difference here is that you want to refer to a property of the class object (which is what `typeof` supplies), a.k.a. a static property, not a property of the type defined by an instance of that class (which is what `PointerSystem` as a type normally means).